# Test for `tar` support of `--includes` versus `--wildcards` options

Tags: tar

Some tar versions seem to support the `--wildcards` flag whereas others do not and support instead `--includes`. Does any know which versions support which, and if there is a way to test for support of one or the other?

Comment: Maybe `tar --help | grep -- --wildcards` and `tar --help | grep -- --includes`?

Comment: `tar` supports none of both, you are probably talking about `gtar`.

Answer (score 1):

Ask tar. At the top of your scripts, set up a couple of test functions to tar /dev/null, and check status. Most .configure scripts do dozens of tests like this.

```
Paul--) tar &>/dev/null cvf /dev/null --includes /dev/null; echo $?
64
Paul--) tar &>/dev/null cvf /dev/null --wildcards /dev/null; echo $?
0
Paul--)
```